# Informative Materials | Asking for resources out of scope?

Tags: discussion

Is asking about people's experiences with various literature in order to draw inspiration (writing & grammar wise, not story related) and to learn other writing styles out of scope for this page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, I'm afraid so.

There might be on topic questions that draw on these things but, as you phrased it, it's [off topic](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Asking about existing literature is explicitly [off topic](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Fair enough - and I worded it that way deliberately in order to get a direct result. I saw what you linked, but wasn't sure if there was an exception (some SE sites make exceptions) when searching for resources.

Comment: @JCrosby Yeah, we have a [tag:resources] tag but it's for resources directly about writing.  Where your example goes off topic is because it's about brainstorming/generating ideas.  Learning about writing styles is too broad but a more focused version *might* work.  But is likely to be a duplicate.